# Uniqueness in automorphism of the disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening, I need some explanation about the definition of uniqueness in the following problem.

There is theorem:

If f is an automorphism of the disc, then there exist $θ ∈ R$ and $α∈D$ such that $f(z)$ = $e^{iθ}$ $(\frac{α -z}{1 - α\bar{z}})$ where $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, $e^{iθ}$ is rotation and $0≤θ<2π$.

Question is to show that in this expression, $θ$ and $α$ are unique. 
What does uniqueness mean here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: unique means if $\theta$ and $\alpha$ work and $\theta'$ and $\alpha'$ also work, then $\theta=\theta'$ and $\alpha=\alpha'$

Comment: Oh, so I need to define new variables first, and then by the following theorem, show that their functions are equal?

Comment: show that if the automorphism functions are the same then the parameters $\theta$ and $\alpha$ are the same

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique means that if $f_1(z)=e^{i\theta_1}\left(\dfrac{\alpha_1-z}{1-\alpha_1 \bar z}\right)$ is the same function as $f_2(z)=e^{i\theta_2}\left(\dfrac{\alpha_2-z}{1-\alpha_2 \bar z}\right)$ --

that is, they are equal for all values of $z$ -- where $\theta_1,\theta_2\in[0,2\pi)$, then $\theta_1=\theta_2$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.